# Finding Expected Value of vector length?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

We build a vector of digits, such that every time we pick a number randomly from {0,1,2,3,...,9} (For each digit the possibility of picking it is equal this 1/10 and not related to previous choices). We stop building out vector at the **first time** each digit appears at least once (Which means the last digit appears exactly once or else we can have a shorter vector which is a contradiction) Now I want to calculate Expected value of length of the vector created.

How can I solve this, I tried with indicators but don't think of any specific indicator what will be helpful here.

Comment: [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: @angryavian can you kindly reword what is written there, it's way coplicated

Answer (score 1):

We can split up the procedure into several waiting times.

Let $T_1$ be the number of draws before seeing the first new number. We have $T_1=1$ since the first draw will give you the first new number.

Let $T_2$ be the number of *subsequent* draws before seeing the second new number. So for instance, if your sequence is $3,3,3,3,1$, then $T_2=4$ since your first new number is "3", and you had to draw $3,3,3,1$ before seeing the second new number "1".

Let $T_3$ be the number of subsequent draws before seeing the third new number, and so on.

In the end, the total number of draws is $T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{10}$. By linearity of expectation,
$$E[T_1 + T_2 + \cdots + T_{10}] = E[T_1] + E[T_2] + \cdots + E[T_{10}],$$
so it suffices to compute each expectation separately.

Recognize that $T_i$ is a geometric distribution. In a sequence of independent draws of successes (seeing the $i$th new number) and failures (seeing an old number), it counts the number of draws until the first success. Note that a success her happens with probability $1 - \frac{i-1}{n}$ since there are $i-1$ "old" numbers you have already seen so far. You can then refer to your prior knowledge about the expectation of a geometric random variable to compute $E[T_i]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a similar problem.

Suppose I had a set of $p$ elements, and a subset of $q\leq p$ elements. What is the expected number of draws with replacement from the set of $p$ elements before we get one of the $q$ elements?

The answer is $\frac pq$.

So, our answer is $$\frac{10}1+\frac{10}2+\ldots+\frac{10}{10}=\frac{7381}{252}$$

Comment: Sorry But I didn't understand /q can you kindly explain every step? I'm more interested in formal solution plus understanding and not in final answers